# Inno Setup: Resize uninstall progress form image

Tags: resize, inno-setup

How to resize the uninstall's `WizardSmallBitmapImage` to these dimensions?

```pascal
Left := ScaleX(0);
Width := ScaleX(500);
Height := ScaleY(60);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set this in the [`InitializeUninstallProgressForm` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeUninstallProgressForm).

```pascal
procedure InitializeUninstallProgressForm();
begin
  with UninstallProgressForm do
  begin
    WizardSmallBitmapImage.Left := ScaleX(0);
    WizardSmallBitmapImage.Width := MainPanel.Width;
    WizardSmallBitmapImage.Height := MainPanel.Height;

    PageDescriptionLabel.Visible := False;
    PageNameLabel.Visible := False;
  end;
end;
```

[image: Stretched uninstall image]